# Sequential Call of API in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, axios

I need to upload multiple images but I also need to upload them one by one.
I wanted to upload them sequentially. First, you need to wait for the previous API response before calling another API response. How will I do it?
Currently is that I'm calling them in parallel. Whoever upload image API response has finished first, will be displayed.

```
export const uploadPhotos =
  ({ photos, size, controller }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    await Promise.all(
      photos.forEach(async (photo, index) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("photo", photo);

        dispatch({ type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_START, size });
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${API_URL}/photos/upload`,
            formData,
            {
              onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
                dispatch(setUploadProgress({ id: index, loaded, total }));
              },
              signal: controller.signal,
            }
          );

          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAILURE,
            payload: error,
          });
        }
      })
    );
  };

export const setUploadProgress = (progress) => ({
  type: constants.SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS,
  payload: progress,
});

export const resetUploadData = () => ({
  type: constants.RESET_UPLOAD_DATA,
});

export const setOverallSize = (data) => ({
  type: constants.SET_OVERALL_SIZE,
  payload: data,
});
```

Comment: First `await Promise.all(photos.forEach(async () => {}))` will have no effect. `forEach` does not return a value. You want a map.
You can loop using `for (const value of myArry)` and do your async call in the for body (you may get an eslint error though.

Comment: @GabrielPichot. are you able to refactor the code and put it as an answer below? `await Promise.all(photos.forEach(async () => {}))` <- this one calls the API one by one but does parallel call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `await Promise.all(photos.forEach(async () => {}))` will have no effect.
`forEach` does not return a value so you want `.map` instead.

But for sequential calls, something like this is preferred:

```js
export const uploadPhotos =
  ({ photos, size, controller }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    for (const [index, photos] of photos.entries()) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("photo", photo);

        dispatch({ type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_START, size });
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${API_URL}/photos/upload`,
            formData,
            {
              onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
                dispatch(setUploadProgress({ id: index, loaded, total }));
              },
              signal: controller.signal,
            }
          );

          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAILURE,
            payload: error,
          });
        }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Looks great! Is there another way without using `for (let index = 0; index < photos.length; ++index)`. I wanted to use modern JS. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to use the `array.entries` method.